# Hastie "statistical learning" 2.28. Least squares and covariance

Tags: self-study

In Hasties book "statistical learning", just above equation 2.28, it says that $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X} \rightarrow NCov(X)$ (when $N$ is large and $E(X)=0$).

Why is this true?

$Cov(X)$ is obviously $Cov(X,X)$, and since $Cov(X,X) = Var(X)$ and $E(X)=0$, $Cov(X)=E(X^2)$. So the original equation says that $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\rightarrow NE(X^2)$.

But, why is $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ scalar? Shoudn't this be a p x p  matrix? Where p is the dimensionality.

This is a book that requires a lot of work, apperently...

Comment: hi, welcome to CV. What's $X$ defined as? If it is $1\times p$, then $X^T$ is $p\times 1$, so $X^T X$ is indeed a matrix. If it is $p\times 1$, then $X^T X$ is a scalar.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it's that simple, I just thought that it should we written as $X_i$.

Comment: But I still don’t get that result. Where does N come into the equation? N is the number of samples…

Comment: I don't know. You probably have to provide more context in the question body about what the different terms are

Answer (score 2):

$X = (X_1, \ldots, X_p)$ is a random vector with $p$ entries (not a scalar random variable).

The expectation of this random vector is denoted $E[X] = (E[X_1], \ldots, E[X_p])$.

The [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) of this random vector is denoted $\text{Cov}(X)$; it is a $p \times p$ matrix whose $(i, j)$ entry is $\text{Cov}(X_i, X_j)$.

$\mathbf{X}$ is an $N \times p$ matrix where each row is an i.i.d. draw from the distribution of the random vector $X$.

The sample covariance matrix $\frac{1}{N} \mathbf{X}^\top \mathbf{X}$ is a $p \times p$ matrix whose $(i, j)$ entry is $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_{n, i} X_{n, j}$. For each $n$, we have $E[X_{n, i} X_{n, j}] = \text{Cov}(X_i, X_j)$, so $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_{n, i} X_{n, j}$ tends to $\text{Cov}(X_i, X_j)$ by the law of large numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This made things more clear. This book assumes that you know a more than «beginner statistics».